# 2 adverbs of frequency in one sentence. 'always' and 'every day'

Tags: adverbs, present-simple

is it acceptable to use 'always' and 'every day' in one sentence?

example:

*He always enjoys participating in our activities every day.*

I am not a native speaker, but this sounds unnatural for me and has no semantic sense.
Clarify please, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that sentence is fine. It might mean, for example, that last year he enjoyed participating in our activities every day, he currently enjoys participating in our activities every day, and he is expected to enjoy participating in our activities every day in the future. In other words, "every day" focuses on the day-to-day timeframe, while "always" focuses on a much longer timeframe. It's entirely correct if that is the author's intended meaning.

Comment: Yes, so long as "every day" means something different than "always", it's OK.